# My CSS works fine until I zoom in closely. Can anyone see why?

Tags: css, zooming, accordion

My CSS seems to work fine. Even the variables work kind of nicely. My problem however is that when I use the browser (I'm using Chrome), the pieces of my accordion seperate for some reason.

I know the likelyhood of a user zooming in this far are slim but I'd prefer the solution to work correctly.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sparx1981/7nm4qypw/92/)

```
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<!--jQuery file referenced to allow document ready loading-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--END jQuery Reference-->
<style type="text/css">
  :root {
    --bar_width_height: 400px;
    --Import_Height: 15px;
    --bar_thickness: 50px;
    --page_size: calc(50px + var(--bar_width_height));
    --half_bar_width_height: calc(var(--bar_width_height)/2);
    --negative_bar_width_height: calc(0px - var(--bar_width_height));
    --half_bar_thickness: calc(var(--bar_thickness)/2);
    --translateY: calc(var(--half_bar_width_height) - var(--half_bar_thickness));
    --translateX: calc(var(--half_bar_width_height) - var(--half_bar_thickness));
    --translateX2: calc(var(--translateY) - 1px);
    --translateY2: calc(var(--translateY) - 5px);
    --Calculated_Import_Height: calc(var(--translateY) - var(--half_bar_thickness) - var(--Import_Height));
  }

  .panel-heading {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    height: var(--bar_thickness);
  }

  .panel-default>.panel-heading {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-color: #ddd;
  }

  .panel {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  }

  .accordion-wrapper {
    display: block;
    height: 350px;
    max-height: 100%;
  }

  #accordion {
    max-width: var(--bar_width_height);
    margin-left: 15px;
  }

  .panel-group {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-300px) rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-300px) rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: right top;
    -o-transform: translateX(-300px) rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform-origin: right top;
    transform: translateX(var(--negative_bar_width_height)) rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: right top;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }

  .panel-body {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: left top;
    -o-transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform-origin: left top;
    transform: translateX(0%) rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    height: var(--page_size);
    position: relative;
  }

  .h4 {
    transform: translateX(25%) translateY(-98rem)rotate(0deg);
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }

  .h4 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  .header_label {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #000;
  }

  .header_bar {
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0px 50px 50px 0px;
    height: var(--bar_thickness);
    transform: translateX(var(--translateX2)) translateY(var(--translateY2)) rotate(90deg);
    background-color: #20c997;
    ;
  }

  .import_here {
    transform: translateX(var(--Calculated_Import_Height)) translateY(var(--translateY2)) rotate(90deg);
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    "

  }

  td {
    height: 50px;
  }

  }

</style>





<!-- Start Lower Accordian -->
<div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="accordion-wrapper">
          <div aria-multiselectable="true" class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" id="headingOne" role="tab" style="border-color:#676668;     background-color: #676668; padding: 10px 45px; text-align:right; ">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a aria-controls="collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" role="button" style="color: #000;">Rulesets</a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div aria-labelledby="headingOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in show" id="collapseOne" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="header_bar" style="border-color:#676668; background-color: #676668; ">
                  <a aria-controls="collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" class="header_label" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" role="button">Rulesets</a>
                </div>
                <div class="import_here">Page A</div>
                <div class="panel-body"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" id="headingTwo" role="tab" style="border-color:#F8BE2E;     background-color: #F8BE2E; padding: 10px 45px; text-align:right; ">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a aria-controls="collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" role="button" style="color: #000;">Rule Details</a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div aria-labelledby="headingTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseTwo" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="header_bar" style="border-color:#F8BE2E; background-color: #F8BE2E;">
                  <a aria-controls="collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" class="header_label" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" role="button">Rule Details</a>
                </div>
                <div class="import_here">Page B</div>
                <div class="panel-body"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" id="headingThree" role="tab" style="border-color:#FED561;     background-color: #FED561; padding: 10px 45px; text-align:right; ">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a aria-controls="collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" role="button" style="color: #000;">Thresholds</a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div aria-labelledby="headingThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseThree" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="header_bar" style="border-color:#FED561; background-color: #FED561;">
                  <a aria-controls="collapseThree" aria-expanded="true" class="header_label" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" role="button">Thresholds</a>
                </div>
                <div class="import_here">Page C</div>
                <div class="panel-body"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" id="headingFour" role="tab" style="border-color:#FFE497;     background-color: #FFE497;      padding: 10px 45px; text-align:right;   ">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a aria-controls="collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFour" role="button" style="color: #000;">Rebates</a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div aria-labelledby="headingFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseFour" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="header_bar" style="border-color:#FFE497; background-color: #FFE497; ">
                  <a aria-controls="collapseFour" aria-expanded="true" class="header_label" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFour" role="button">Rebates</a>
                </div>
                <div class="import_here">
                  <div>
                    Page D
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" id="headingFive" role="tab" style="border-color:#FFF1CE;     background-color: #FFF1CE; padding: 10px 45px; text-align:right; ">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a aria-controls="collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFive" role="button" style="color: #000;">Invoices</a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div aria-labelledby="headingFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseFive" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="header_bar" style="border-color:#FFF1CE; background-color: #FFF1CE;">
                  <a aria-controls="collapseFive" aria-expanded="true" class="header_label" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseFive" role="button">Invoices</a>
                </div>
                <div class="import_here">Page E</div>
                <div class="panel-body"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Lower Accordian -->
```

Comment: It's impossible to program for all levels of zoom, the best you can hope for is to make things responsive so they can scale better.

Comment: So my code is actually fine?

Comment: It's not responsive if that's what you're asking